# How To Copy Project Files To Output And Import Code From Same Project?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

I would like to have the output folder for a particular project (let's call it `TestProject`) in a solution have all of the elements necessary for publishing a different project (let's call it `AppProject`) in the same solution. The intention is that `AppProject` will then be published by `TestProject` by running `dotnet publish AppProject` as the execution context of `TestProject` will be `TestProject`'s output folder.

I would also like to have `AppProject`'s source available to `TestProject` so I can import code from `AppProject`.

Inside of `TestProject.csproj` I have added the following code...

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\AppProject\**" Exclude="..\AppProject\bin\**;..\AppProject\obj\**" Pack="true">
   <Link>AppProject\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
   <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works well and copies the entirety of `AppProject`, minus any created artifacts, into the right place for publishing by `TestProject`. I would like to have the code from `AppProject` available in `TestProject` however and have added the following code to `TestProject.csproj` as well...

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\AppProject\AppProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This causes a lot of errors from msbuild whenever attempting to build on Linux specifically. These errors relate to the file already existing.

Is it possible to modify the setup of `TestProject.csproj` to make it possible for this to work on Linux? Is it possible to solve this problem better in a completely separate way?

Comment: Don't use the standard output directory for the copy of `AppProject` that will be published. Or don't copy the `AppProject` project and instead have `TestProject` run `dotnet publish AppProject` against the original project but specify a custom destination for the publish. Or create two separate test projects: one that uses the code via a `ProjectReference` and one that exercises the publish.

Comment: Replacing the `None` item group with a more explicit `Content` may help.

Comment: In most cases `None` and `Content` are handled the same.